# RDLC : How to add rowspan

Tags: rdlc

Now I can add colspan with Merge Cell command.
But I can't find the way to add rowspan.

Could anybody help me please.

Comment: I am getting the same problem here. Can anybody suggest?

Comment: [So sad](http://forums.asp.net/t/1325930.aspx/1)

Comment: Hi OammieR, did u solve this?

Comment: Hi Chandra, I can't but I have another way to makeshift. Add new row and remove line's border in between of 2 rows.(not sure that remove or change color)

Comment: @ChandraPrakash May be a mistake that tell you to add new row. Just remove line's border in between of 2 rows.

Comment: Thank you very much:) for now it's working properly, lets see the later issues.